# Wordpress WP_Login

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying do get a java mesage after login in wordpress.
Here is my code:

```
function myFunction()
{
?>
<script>
alert('test');
</script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'myFunction' );
```

I had a sidebar login widget. If i replace wp_login with get_header it works.
Why does the wp_login not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp_login` action hook is triggered **ONLY** when a user logs in by the `wp_signon()` function. It is the very last action taken in the function, immediately following the `wp_set_auth_cookie()` call.

See the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon).